# Assigning array elements to variables PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array with the names of medication which the user is currently taking. On the webpage, I want to display radio buttons with the name of each of the medications, which are currently being taken, next to them. The code I have for the array is;

```
//Current Entries Section
$CurrentMedsQuery = "SELECT Name FROM `".$username."medication` WHERE Status='Current';";
$RunMedsQuery = mysql_query($CurrentMedsQuery) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$CurrentMedsQuery);
$Count = mysql_num_rows($RunMedsQuery);
$CurrentMedsArray = array();
while ($CurrentMedEntries = mysql_fetch_array($RunMedsQuery)) {
    array_push($CurrentMedsArray,$CurrentMedEntries['Name']);
    }

    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('CurrentMedsArray', $CurrentMedsArray);   

    while ($Count < 0) {

    }

    $FirstMedEntry = ($CurrentMedsArray["0"]);
```

Then on my HTML form, I have the following code which successfully displays the name of the first element in the array as I want it to;

```
<form method="post" name="currentmeds" action="">

<input type="radio" name="med1" value="med1"><?php echo $FirstMedEntry;?><br>

</form>
```

But my question is, I will not know how many current medication entries the user has, therefore I cannot continuously use `echo $FirstMedEntry, echo $SecondMedEntry` and so on..I figure I need some sort of loop, and help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Changed to the following as suggested;

```
//Current Entries Section
echo '<form method="post" name="currentmeds" action="">';
$CurrentMedsQuery = "SELECT Name FROM `".$username."medication` WHERE Status='Current';";
$RunMedsQuery = mysql_query($CurrentMedsQuery) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$CurrentMedsQuery);
$Count = mysql_num_rows($RunMedsQuery);
$count = 1;
while ($CurrentMedEntries = mysql_fetch_row($RunMedsQuery)) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="med' . $count . '" value="med' . $count . '">' . $CurrentMedEntries . '<br>';
    $count++;
}
echo '</form>';
```

But now receiving this error;
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla-Lifestyle\components\com_jumi\files\medication.php on line 238

Line 238:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="med' . $count . '" value="med' . $count . '">' . $CurrentMedEntries . '<br>';
```

Comment: Wait, why do you need to store it in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$CurrentMedsArray` contains all your data, so you can just loop through it and display the values:

```
<form method="post" name="currentmeds" action="">
    <?php foreach ($CurrentMedsArray as $key => $entry): ?>
    <input type="radio" name="med<?=$key+1?>" value="med<?=$key+1?>"><?=$entry;?><br>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

If the array isn't needed for this purpose, this could be modified and displayed inside your `while` loop instead. Also note `<?=$var;?>` is  the short syntax for `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

Comment: I accept your answer and voted up. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an array and I'd suggest you don't. Just do the following:

```
<?php   
echo '<form method="post" name="currentmeds" action="">';
$CurrentMedsQuery = "SELECT Name FROM `".$username."medication` WHERE Status='Current'";
$RunMedsQuery = mysql_query($CurrentMedsQuery) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$CurrentMedsQuery);
$Count = mysql_num_rows($RunMedsQuery);
$count = 1;
while ($CurrentMedEntries = mysql_fetch_row($RunMedsQuery)) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="med' . $count . '" value="med' . $count . '">' . $CurrentMedEntries['name'] . '<br>';
    $count++;
}
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Although I strongly urge you to not use `mysql_`. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: I tried this method and I get the following error:Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla-Lifestyle\components\com_jumi\files\medication.php on line 238  that is this line echo '<input type="radio" name="med' . $count . '" value="med' . $count . '">' . $CurrentMedEntries . '<br>';

Comment: @user3266484 My bad. It shouldn't be `mysql_fetch_array()`. Should be `mysql_fetch_row()`. Fixed.

Comment: I am still having the same issue after changing to mysql_fetch_row() any other suggestions? If not, no worries, im sure ill figure it out eventually..

Comment: @user3266484 Because you had to change it to `$CurrentMedEntries['Name']`. You fetched the row but didn't indicate what you want to concat to the string.